# Error : Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction / Limit Delete Query with join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have the table having duplicate entries against `column` "`image_url`" now i want to remove only duplicates and keep just one record of each?

here is my query i tried :

```
DELETE t1
FROM
    ad_images_copy t1
JOIN ad_images_copy t2 ON t2.image_url = t1.image_url
AND t2.id < t1.id
```

[reference link for remove duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432093/remove-duplicate-rows-based-on-one-column-value)
but it gave me the `error`

> Error : Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

now i want to Limit this query because i have to much records.

i tried by adding `limit` in last but it not work for me .

```
DELETE t1
    FROM
        ad_images_copy t1
    JOIN ad_images_copy t2 ON t2.image_url = t1.image_url
    AND t2.id < t1.id
limit 100 ;
```

help if any other way to do this.

Comment: Is that field indexed on both tables?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is that `image_url` and `id` are indexed on both tables. (Probably `id` is the primary key, so it'll be indexed, but you should check that `image_url` is indexed.) If not, add indexes.

If so, you might try avoiding the locking by doing it in two steps. Are your rows immutable? If they are, then you can use a `SELECT` query to find all the rows you want to delete, and then use some batched `DELETE`s to get rid of them. This means that you won't end up locking the whole table.

It's safe to do it this way as long as you know that the rows you're looking at aren't going to change, or get removed from `t2`, between the `SELECT` and the `DELETE`.

Comment: no image_url is not indexed and currently it has duplicate entries , now how can i add index on it

Comment: Ah, you need to index it on both tables! `ALTER TABLE \`t1\` ADD INDEX \`idx_image_url\` (\`image_url\`)` should do it for `t1`, and similarly for `t2`. It'll take some time.

Comment: i tried this multiple time but it give me the error LOST CONNECTION TO MYSQL SERVER DURING QURING ..

Comment: Well, it's the right query. You might need to experiment with your timeout settings in whatever client you're using. Or add the indexes from the command line.

Comment: yes i tried it with command line , and query was in progress from last 30 minutes :(

Comment: Yes, it might take a very long time (even overnight), depending on how many rows you have.