# How do i get the unique records in a UNION where one column is null for one part of the union?

Tags: sql, union

I get a daily feed of products in a staging table. I want to update the actual tables with records from the staging table.

Heres my query.

```
SELECT NUll, ColumnA, ColumnB FROM stagingTable
UNION
SELECT ID, ColumnA, ColumnB From actualTable
```

This gives me

```
NULL 10  100
NULL 20  200
NULL 30  300
1    10  100
```

I want to remove the duplicate record as that record is already in the actual table.

```
NULL 10 100
```

Comment: Maybe you should refactor your query to it using join? Or you can take a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432093/remove-duplicate-rows-based-on-one-column-value

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use `not exists`:

```
SELECT ID, ColumnA, ColumnB From actualTable
UNION ALL
SELECT NUll, s.ColumnA, s.ColumnB
FROM stagingTable s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM actualTable t WHERE t.columnA = s.columnA);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it slightly differently from the first answer and use a subquery for the staging table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
COALESCE(T1.ID,T2.ID) AS ID
,T1.ColumnA
,T1.ColumnB

FROM
    (
        SELECT
        NULL AS ID
        ,ColumnA
        ,ColumnB

        FROM
        #stagingtable 
    ) AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #actualtable T2
ON T1.ColumnA = T2.ColumnA
    AND T1.ColumnB = T2.ColumnB
```